# XCode: Endless sign-in windows when trying to provision

Tags: xcode, provisioning

I'm trying to provision a second device for testing in XCode and am having some trouble.  I'm following along with [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html), and get as far as clicking the Refresh button in the Library's Provisioning Profiles section.

Then, the "Sign in with your Apple ID" window pops up and despite entering my Apple ID and clicking Log In, it just keeps popping up again.  There are no warnings or anything, it just keeps popping up.  I verified the Apple ID by logging into Apple's developer website and everything seems fine with the username/password.  Any ideas?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: have you tried adding the device from the website? I know it isn't the answer, but it might work for now.

Comment: Hi Joe, that did do the trick, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe's tip did the trick.  I added the device from the website.